# How trampoline work with multimethods in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

Im trying to understand how `trampoline` is used to support mutual recursion with tail recursion. However im lost when both the example below compiles with the same result. I believed that each `defmethod` had to return a function as in example 2 below. But this is clearly not the case since example 1 works just as fine. So are the two implementations below tail recursive and identical in there performance or what is the difference between them?

Example 1:

```
(defmulti jump :beff)
(defmethod jump 1 [{:keys [beff]}]                                         
      (print beff)                                                             
      (jump {:beff (inc beff)}))                                               
(defmethod jump 2 [{:keys [beff]}]                                         
      (print beff)                                                             
      (jump {:beff (inc beff)}))                                               
(defmethod jump :default [{:keys [beff]}]                                  
      (print beff))                                                            
(def v {:beff 1})     
(trampoline jump v)
```

Example 2:

```
(defmulti jump :beff)
(defmethod jump 1 [{:keys [beff]}]                                         
      (print beff)                                                             
      #(jump {:beff (inc beff)}))                                               
(defmethod jump 2 [{:keys [beff]}]                                         
      (print beff)                                                             
      #(jump {:beff (inc beff)}))                                               
(defmethod jump :default [{:keys [beff]}]                                  
      #(print beff))                                                            
(def v {:beff 1})     
(trampoline jump v)
```

Comment: Try executing Example 1 with a value that will recurse several 1000 times before producing a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 1 is wrong and Example 2 is correct.

the first one only works because it's recuring only twice and doesn't blow the stack. The call to trampoline does nothing because the function never returns a function, so the trampoline function simply returns the value it returned.

it works in the same way this does:

```
user> (trampoline #(inc 41))
42
```

In this case trampoline makes the initial call to the function, then checks to see if the returned value is a function. Since the result is the number 42 it simply returns this. in Example 1 trampoline makes the first call, which recurs within it's self all the way through and returns a value that is not a function. Trampoline then returns this value without "bouncing" at all. Here's another example that does it wrong in the same way:

```
user> (trampoline (fn example
                    ([] (example 4))
                    ([x] (if (pos? x) (do (println x) (example (dec x)))))))
4
3
2
1
nil
```